# AngularJS : How to load an ng-click function of a radio button on loading of the page?

Tags: angularjs

There are 2 radio buttons, `offline` and `online`:

```
<input type="radio" name="mode" ng-click="offlineFn()" >Offline
<input type="radio" name="mode" ng-click="onlineFn()">Online
```

ng-click of offline is ng-click="offlineFn()".

This fn should be called on loading of the page itself.

Comment: put function inside ng-init= "offlineFn() "  in radio button..

Comment: if you just want to call the function, then best way is to put it inside ng-init tag.

Comment: but when i click online and then go back to offline it is not working

Comment: than use both ng-init and ng-click..

Comment: ng-init will initialize at page load, ng-click will work for you on click event..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="mode"ng-click="offlineFn()" ng-init="offlineFn()" >Offline
<input type="radio" name="mode" ng-init="onlineFn()" ng-click="onlineFn()">Online
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-init: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

```
data-ng-init="offlineFn()"
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is do this in the controller like so:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.offlineFn = function () {
        //do stuff
        alert('offlineFn');
    };

    $scope.offlineFn();

    //do other stuff
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tC77svq63mERgBqlnVjQ?p=preview). If you switch to page 2 and then back to page one you will see the alert.

If you read the [documentation of ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) it says:

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat